# $_POST Array = 0 after submit

Tags: php, html, forms

On submit,i send the form-data to "`log-reg-redirect.php`"

And when i submit the form it returned a error.

I've checked many times but don't know why this problem occurred

Anybody help me :((

[image: Image 1]
[image]

Comment: Sorry this is my first time i use stackoverflow

Comment: Tip: Images of text are annoying; _just put the text_.

Comment: Please, what is the result of var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude Array = null ( 0 ), I expected it would be executing "login-register-system.php" and redirect $_Server['Request_url']. But it did not happen

Comment: After header(...) you lost the POST Data ... so you run in first ... with POST redirect and then you have no post

Comment: @donald123 No! The code wrapped in first if condition won't execute (because $_POST Array = 0 and i don't know why).